# WPF DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, binding

Есть у меня контрол, в котором прописан `DependencyProperty`:

```
public string StringData
{
   get { return (string)GetValue(StringDataProperty); }
   set { SetValue(StringDataProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty StringDataProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("StringData", typeof(string), typeof(MyView), new 
PropertyMetadata("", PropertyChangedCallback));
```

В родительском контроле есть свойтсво:

```
public string Field1 {get;set;}
```

Я делаю `Binding` к этому полю. Если сделать через `RelativeSource`, то все работает:

```
<Views:MyView StringData="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=Field1}"/>
```

Но если мы пропишем у родительского пропишем `DataContext` и будем биндиться без `RelativeSource`:

```
<Views:MyView StringData="{Binding Path=Field1}"/>
```

Tо получаем сообщение:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 :
> BindingExpression path error:
> 'Field1' property not found on
> 'object' ''MyView'
> (Name='')'.
> BindingExpression:Path=Field1;
> DataItem='MyView'
> (Name=''); target element is
> 'MyView' (Name='');
> target property is 'StringData' (type
> 'String')

Какого черта он это поле ищет во `MyView`??? Он же должен его искать в родительском???

Если рядом положить обычный `TextBox`, то в нем все отображается как надо:

```
<Views:MyView StringData="{Binding Path=Field1}"/>
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Field1}"/>
```

Объясните пожалуйста что происходит?

Comment: Что пишется в датаконтекст родительского? Есть ли у MyView датаконтекст?

Comment: Да, я действительно устанавливаю DataContext

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотрите.

`Binding` по умолчанию происходит к `DataContext`'у. Когда вы написали

```
<Views:MyView StringData="{Binding Path=Field1}"/>
```

ваша привязка стала происходить к нему.

Если

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Field1}"/>
```

рядом работает так, как надо, судя по всему, у `Views:MyView` каким-то образом меняется `DataContext`. Проверьте ваш `DataContext`, может, вы устанавливаете его в code-behind?

Кстати, сообщение об ошибке говорит, что ваш `DataContext` для `MyView` — объект типа `StoredProcedureItemView`, а `Binding` происходит не к `Field1`, а к `StrData`. Это правильно, так и надо?

Comment: @VladD, да, DataContext у меня был установлен, для удобства прописывания привязок в моем контроле. Честно говоря, стыдно признаться, первый раз слышу про такое поведение биндинга...

> Кстати, сообщение об ошибке говорит, что ваш DataContext для MyView — объект типа StoredProcedureItemView, а Binding происходит не к Field1, а к StrData. Это правильно, так и надо?

это я менял на имена покороче для наглядности и не все поменял

Comment: @Donil: Идея WPF состоит в том, что View (контролы) являются _визуальным представлением_ для своего `DataContext`'а (который согласно MVVM есть ViewModel). Поэтому для удобства по умолчанию привязка идёт не к «своим» свойствам, а именно к свойствам `DataContext`'а.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, теперь буду иметь в виду.

Comment: @Donil: делайте так:

    <UserControl x:Class="Views:MyView" ...>
        <StackPanel>
            <Border
                DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}">
                <!-- здесь внутри ваши привязки идут к свойствам контрола -->
            </Border>
            <Border>
                <!-- А здесь - к внешнему DataContext'у -->
            </Border>
        </StackPanel>
    </UserControl>